# How to set a session and check if it's set in other pages

Tags: php, session

How do I set a session in PHP, (for a log in form) and then on a page called view.php - if the session hasn't been logged in, to not display the page, but if it is, display it?
The login part is working, and tells me if i've logged in, and whether username or password etc is incorrect, however, I want it to store a cookie/session when you do log in, and then take you to view.php -> but if you're not logged in and try acces view.php - to not allow you.

Code is currently:

```
<?php
require 'db/connect.php';
// CONNECT TO MYSQLI
$db2 or die(mysqli_errno());

// FETCH DATA FROM FORM USING METHOD POST
// IF BUTTON NAME "LOGIN" IS SET
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {





// FETCH DATA FROM INPUT FIELD
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($db2, $_POST['user']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($db2, $_POST['pass']);

  // CHECK ALL FIELD HAS BEEN FILLED UP
 if ($user && $pass != "") {

   // QUERY FROM DATABASE
  $query = mysqli_query($db2, "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='".$user."'");
  $checkuser = mysqli_num_rows($query);


   // CHECK IF USERNAME EXIST ON DATABASE
  if($user != $checkuser) {

  }
else{
    echo 'Invalid Credentials';
}
   // FETCHING PASSWORD IN DATABASE WHERE USERNAME COINCIDES
 while  ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

   $checkpass= $row['password'];


    // CHECK IF ENTERED PASSWORD MEETS THE USERNAME PASSWORD
   if ($pass == $checkpass) {




     // IF ALL OKAY SET SESSION
setcookie("user", $user, time()+7200);
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (60 * 60 * 60);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user'] = 1;
echo 'you are logged in';
    exit();

   } else {

     // SET VARIABLE THAT'LL SHOW IF USER PASSWORD IS INCORRECT
   echo "Invalid Credentials";

   }
  }
 } else {

  // SET VARIABLE IF ALL FIELD ARE NOT FILLED UP
 $error = "Please enter a username and password.";
 echo $error;
 }
}
?>


<title>*******</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css">
<div style="text-align: center;">

<form action="" method="post" id="loginForm">
<span class="input">Username: <input type="text" name="user" maxlength="16"></span>
<span class="input">Password: <input type="password" name="pass">
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yous can write a function to check whether the session user is set and if it's not set then redirect to a log in page.

```
function redirect(){
return !isset($_SESSION['user']);
}
```

And in your view.php file start your session and include the following condition.

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
//if session doesn't have a username it will redirect to login.php page
if(redirect()){
header("Location: login.php");
die();
}
?>
```